# Median of 2-D Matrix (Minesweeper)

Tags: java, matrix, median

I am trying to solve this assignment but not able to figure out the logic on how to get the median here.

Question:- Find the median of a 2D-Matrix. (which is a Minesweeper game's result). Only horizontal and vertical values (1's) are counted. (Please click on the link for sample results).

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xTiO.png)

Solution:-

```
public static int findMedian2(int[][] matrix)
{
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] == 1)
            {
                size++;
                dfs(matrix, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return size;
}
private static void dfs(int[][] grid, int r, int c)
{
    if(r < 0 || r >= grid.length || c < 0 || c >= grid[r].length || grid[r][c] == 0)
        return;

    grid[r][c] = 0;
    dfs(grid, r - 1, c);
    dfs(grid, r + 1, c);
    dfs(grid, r, c - 1);
    dfs(grid, r, c + 1);
}
```

So far I am able get the size. The size does not really give the right answer here, how do I achieve the median? I am new to matrix related problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:-**
Based on @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans's input I could come up with this:-

```
static int count;
static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
public static int findMedian(int[][] matrix) 
{
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) 
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) 
            {
                dfs(matrix, i, j);
                if (count != 0 && count != 1) 
                {
                    list.add(count);
                }
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // convert list to array
    int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    return findMedian(array);
}
private static void dfs(int[][] grid, int r, int c)
{       
    if(r < 0 || r >= grid.length || c < 0 || c >= grid[r].length || grid[r][c] == 0)
        return;
    grid[r][c] = 0;        
    dfs(grid, r - 1, c);
    dfs(grid, r + 1, c);
    dfs(grid, r, c - 1);
    dfs(grid, r, c + 1);
    count++;
}
/* Median of Unsorted Array to match the results */
private static int findMedian(int[] a) 
{
    // check for even case
    if (a.length % 2 != 0) 
    {
        return a[a.length / 2];
    }
    return (a[(a.length - 1) / 2] + a[a.length / 2]) / 2;
}
```

**Will this be the correct way to calculate median for this question?**

Comment: This... is not what a median is? If you have 2, 3, 6, and 6, where there is no "middle" value, the median is the weighted average of the middle two values, so: (3+6)/2, which is 4.5, not 4. Also, the examples don't even make sense: the first example has a yellow cluster of 4, not 3, so the actual median is 5 (because (4+6)/2 is 5). Same for the second example: there is only one cluster, of 4, so the median is 4.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I aplogize there were some mistakes on the sample results, I have modified the screenshot on the link. Thank you for your input, but what would be the process to store the individual cluster results? I got the median calculation.

Comment: consider building cluster objects, so that instead of looping over each value in the array, you run through the array until you find a `1`, and start a new `Cluster(matrix, x, y)` with (x,y) being the coordinate of that intiail `1`. Then you grow the cluster by checking neighbouring values for whether they are `1` (checking left, down, and right), setting them to `0` in the matrix as you grow so that they get ignored by subsequent checks.When your cluster can't find any more `1`s, that cluster is done. You then try to find a new `1` in your matrix, and repeat.